# Does opening a regular file by `open()` in a C program create a file `/proc/$pid/fd/$number`?

Tags: linux, file-descriptors

In Linux,  I write a C program, which calls [`open()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_(system_call)#C_library_POSIX_definition) to open a regular file and return a file descriptor.

When I run the executable compiled from the C program, is it correct that its process creates a file   `/proc/$pid/fd/$number`, where

- `$pid` is the pid of the process and
- `$number` is the same integer as the file descriptor returned by `open()` in the C program?

Is `/proc/$pid/fd/$number` a symbolic link to the regular file opened by `open()` in the C program?

Answer (score 4):

Why not try it out?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int fd = open("333222.c", 0);
  printf("%d\n", fd);
  sleep(120);
  if (fd >= 0) {
    close(fd);
  }
}
```

Save this as `333222.c`, compile it and run it:

```
gcc -o 333222 333222.c
./333222 &
```

This will show you the pid and the file descriptor (3); use the former to list the file descriptors:

```
ls -l /proc/.../fd
```

and you'll see file descriptor 3 linked to `333222.c`.

To answer your question, `/proc/$pid/fd/$fd` does correspond to the file descriptor `$fd` inside the program running with pid `$pid`, as returned by `open(2)` and so on, and is indeed linked to the actual file that was opened (if it's still there).